# Collect webhook data in chargify

Tags: payment-gateway, webhooks, chargify

I have already created a webhook link like: http://ncbeta.net/proposal/hook/post_index
and configured it.

I am sending an email from this function when creating a subscription. It is working fine, sends an email when creating a subscription or when click on test to simulate the hook.

But actually I need to collect all data sent to web hook by chargify. I have userd $_POST in email body. but it sends a blank email.

How can I collect this data sent by chargify to webhook?
Thanks.

Comment: Generally using $_POST should work.  Can you post your example code so that we can debug it?

Comment: thanks for commenting! it is solved already by this:
$this->email->body("<pre>".print_r($_POST, true));